# How to check for URL parameters with angular1.6?

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, location, angular1.6

I had a scenario where i need to add the params to the URL. If i add as below url is messed up if there are params already included to the URL

```
 /stackoverflow?add=true;
```

But how to check if there are any params and add the new params to it

```
/stackoverflow?alreadyThere=true&add=true
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

Answer (score 0):

Check if $state.params which returns the list of query parameters, is empty. If empty, then add the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check params in your url in the event `$stateChangeStart` of `$rootScope`. Check the `$state` params and apend new parameters if params exist.

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, 
        fromState, fromParams, options) {
        if (toParams.alreadyThere) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('STACKOVERFLOW', {
                alreadyThere: toParams.alreadyThere,
                add: true
            }});
        }
    });
```